# Muxing steps for Fragmented MP4 into Progressive MP4

Tags: video, mp4, video-processing, m4a, fmp4

I am creating an MP4 **muxer** app  using **isobmff** Library.

I have a fragmented MP4. Example structure: `moof/mdat` --> `moof/mdat` etc...

Now I want to transmux the fragmented MP4 into being a progressive MP4. 
 This will be done without external tools like FFmpeg.

**Problem:**

I need help to confirm if the following steps are correct for transmuxing.

(1) Make a Movie Box `moov`,

(2) Make a Track Box `trak` and a Media Box `mdia`.

(3) Calculating All `moof` Box data (such as duration) and allocate that into either the Track or the Media Box (as needed).

(4) ALL found `mdat` Boxes are merged one `mdat` Box.

Is this process **correct** for muxing from Frag-MP4 into a Progressive MP4?

Is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

Comment: I don't use ISOBMFF library so you tell... If you make a `mdia` box then does that library also automatically add inside `mdia` the other expected `minf` and `vmhd` child boxes? Also given a number, can you break that 32-bit integer into (or spread over) 4 array slots? If you can write your own 4 or 8 byte values per integer then you don't need a library to mux. Just fill 4 slots for Size _eg:_ `[0] [0] [0] [9]` then next 4 slots for Name String _eg:_ `["f"] ["t"] ["y"] ["p"]` then paste in the FTYP data content from the fragmented MP4. One down, 19 more to go... Then you have your own muxer.